# Feature selection/extraction in an ANN model for regression

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am trying to fit an ANN model for regression with 15 input parameters.
Some of these parameters are related to each other and the relationship is not linear. Say, one of the input parameters can be expressed as a non-linear function of other parameters. But I don't know these relations exactly because I lack domain knowledge. Is there a way to find these relationships among the input parameters?

I have tried finding these relationships with pandas correlation matrix, couldn't draw any conclusion since it talks about the only linear correlation between 2 parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the non-linear relationship between your input features would be to follow the approach similar to computing Variance Inflation Factor (VIF) which is used to find out the linear relationships between your input features. The modification which we need would be, instead of running a Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) regression to find out the linear relationship between your input features, you can use a neural network in place of OLS which captures the non-linear relationship between your features.

[image: formula]

So your ***f*** will be a OLS for the computing VIF in the regular setting, in our case it will be Neural Network, which is proven to be efficient in capturing non-linear relationships.

And for finding out the VIF in this case instead of [image: formula] we could replace it with the accuracy of the neural network.

[image: formula]

And finally for which ever variable your VIF higher you can conclude that they highly correlated with other features.

Comment: Hi , the higher VIF value indicated that the variable is highly correlated with other variables, but is there a way to find, to which other variables is it correlated the most?

Comment: Well one possible way for doing that would be to run the process pair wise, but it could be computationally expensive!

Comment: If you think this answer helped you resolve your problem, I kindly request you to accept it an answer, as it will help others to find the right answer if they also face similar issues. Thanks in advance! For more details please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers